# Maven build fails, because it does not recognize a .jar added to the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-kafka

In Eclipse I've added the `kafka-clients-jms.jar` to the build path of my project.

I get no errors in Eclipse, but when I run `mvn clean install` it fails, because it can't find the `KafkaJmsConnectionFactory` class which is part of the *.jar* that I've added to the build path.

Not sure how to fix this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually adding a library to Eclipse's build path does not automatically add it to the POM file.

Judging from the missing class, it looks like you are trying to use a library hosted on GitHub in a Maven project: https://github.com/adispennette/apache-kafka-jms

Since GitHub is not a Maven repository, you will need to manually install the artifact to your local repository first.

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=kafka-clients-jms.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.kafka -DartifactId=kafka-clients-jms -Dversion=0.8.2.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then add the following to the POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients-jms</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you manually add the jar to the build path in Eclipse, it's only added to the dependencies in Eclipse, but not the classpath when you run maven from command line. Add the jar to the `dependencies` in your pom.xml.

It's probably advisable to always maintain your dependencies in pom.xml, and use maven's eclipse plugin (or Eclipse's Maven plugin) to keep it in sync with your Eclipse project settings.